# Receiving Junk Characters when messages are consumed using kafka-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, kafka-consumer-api, node-kafka

I Am using the npm package kafka-node version 3.0.1.

However, am receiving junk characters in the message -

```
""M`@$�q��1��N$907959dc-30e9-4e5c-af44-09a4f9062fe1�{"header":{"eventName":"myevent","producer"�'INE",DETECTED"}}"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To remove "junk" characters (unicode unprintable characters) just use `replace`.

```js
const str = "M`@$�q��1��N$907959dc-30e9-4e5c-af44-09a4f9062fe1�";
const res = str.replace(/�/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

You could alternatively check the character code using `filter` and `join`.

```js
const str = "M`@$�q��1��N$907959dc-30e9-4e5c-af44-09a4f9062fe1�";
const res = [...str].filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) != 65533).join("");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for your reply. This is quick fix using javascript. However, am trying to nail down the root cause.